5 V relay coil, drops to 3.3 V when powered ON
This is doing my head in. Issues:

Relay contact gets stuck after only turning it ON/OFF about 5 times.
When 5 V output from Arduino I/O is applied to relay coil, voltage across coil drops to 3.3 V

Relay is RTD34005.
Load is a 500 mA resistive load. BY550-100 diode is across coil.
Arduino I/O can source up to 50 mA.
I tried using 3 same relays, but result is the same.
What's going on here?
UPDATE: all good now. yup, digi-key info about coil current is wrong. so to make it work, relay coil was connected to 5V while other end is connected to Arduino I/O (to provide sink). relay contact no longer stuck after cycling it ON/OFF for more than 100x now. Same result for other relays.
So thanks all!

arduino is unable to supply enough current ... the output voltage sags as a result ... you cannot drive the relay coil directly, it will destroy the output pin circuitry

5V/62Ω = 81mA. What does "stuck" mean?  In the energized or deenergized position

"5V output from Arduino I/O is applied to relay coil" Major mistake here. Your Arduino is probably permanently damaged. Don't do this.

According to the datasheet from the page you linked to (page 1) these are the important figures:

Coil voltage: 5V
Coil resistance: 62Ω
Coil power 0.4W

Before doing any design work, you should always see if these make any sense:
Coil current \$I\$ will be:
$$ I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{5V}{62\Omega} = 80mA $$
This corresponds to power \$P\$ being dissipated in the coil:
$$ P = I \times V = 80mA \times 5V = 0.4W $$
The datasheet seems to be sane, which means the coil current of 14.2mA quoted on Digikey's product summary page is incorrect.
There's no way an Arduino output can source 80mA, and I would even question the claim that it can source 50mA without a significant fall in output potential. Therefore you can't operate this relay coil directly from the Arduino, and you need some kind of buffer in between them.
Here are a couple of designs which will interface your Arduino to the relay:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
On a side note, most microcontroller or IO ICs will have some maximum combined current permissible for all output pins. So even if the Arduino could source 80mA, if you are driving say 3 relays, totalling 240mA, this could still easily exceed the tolerance of the IC, even though you are not exceeding any individual pin's maximum.
The MOSFET (M1, right) solution above doesn't draw any DC current from IN, and would not present any problem in this respect, but the BJT version (Q1 above left) draws this much current from the Arduino output (connected to IN) when high:
$$ I_{IN} = \frac{V_{IN}-V_{BE}}{R_1} = \frac{5V - 0.7V}{1k\Omega} = 4.3mA $$
If you read in the ATMega (the MCU aboard an Arduino UNO) datasheet that total current from all outputs should not exceed 200mA, then the maximum number of relays you can safely operate using this buffer arrangement would be:
$$ N = \frac{200mA}{4.3mA} = 46 $$
Not really an issue for you, I expect, but always necessary to consider.

The 5V relay needs about 80mA.
The Arduino is not any specific MCU but literally no MCU can drive a 80mA relay coil from IO pin directly. It might not work or it may damage.
If your MCU is something like Atmega328P then the 50mA is an absolute maximum rating before damage, not a normal operating condition.
The voltage will also drop with load current, and it is rated to drop about 0.7V at 20mA. The voltage is only 5V if no current is drawn, near 5V with small currents, and definitely not near 5V if an abnormal amount of current is loading the pin.
